# Rename files and there store it to csv using Python

Tags: python, csv, metadata, rename

I want to rename files in subfolders which I can do with this following code.

```
import os

#This is to rename files
def main():
    path = "D:\Proyekan\Data yang udah di extract"
    count = 1

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for i in files:
            fullpath = os.path.join(root,i)
            os.rename(os.path.join(fullpath), os.path.join(root, "Flight_" + str(1000000+count) + ".mat"))

            count += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code works for subfolders so:

`Folder 1` the file names are `Flight_1-Flight_25` and
`Folder 2` the file names are `Flight_26-Flight_27`.

The problem is, I need to list the old name into new files, so I can track it, the folders too. Ex :

`123123` to `Flight 1` in `Folder 1`,
`12313` to `Flight 2` in `Folder 2`,

and so on. Any ideas how? I got lost in trying to figure how

I want the results to be like this:
[image: Like this]

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to also rename the folders? Also you would need to further explain your expected output as it doesn't follow on from your example. You can use [edit] to improve your question.